# MYSQL remove the first comma from a string

Tags: mysql

I have a string variable `SET @my_str=,2,4,7,1` and I want to remove the first char (comma). What I tried is `SET @my_str=substr(@my_str,1)` but it does not work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index is 1-based, so you will need to start at 2:

```
SET @my_str=substr(@my_str,2)
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substr.asp